# how to add gif image into iOS app icon?

Tags: xcode, ios4, ios5

What i see in the Xcode 4.3.2 is to able to add only .png image as a application icon. Is it possible to add .gif image as a application icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from the documentation:

> The filenames can be anything you want, but all image files must be in the PNG format and reside in the top level of your app bundle

[Human Interface Guideleines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)